# POST dictionary on server

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to POST dictionary on server using NSURLSession in objective c.I have gone through tutorials...but still the concept is not clear.Kindly explain and help how this can be done?I have attached the code as suggested.Kindly check it and explain.

```
-(void)sendDetailsToServer:(NSDictionary *)details withToken:(NSString*)token{


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: sessionConfig delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:details options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/detailurl",Url, token]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


    currentSerType = SendUserUpdateDetails;


    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    [dataTask resume];


}






- (IBAction)saveAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {


    NSLog(@"the values stored in dictionary are %@",_userDetailsDictionary);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_userDetailsDictionary forKey:@"UpdatedDetails"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

  Network * connection = [Connection sharedConnection];
    connection.delegate = self;
    [connection sendUserUpdatedDetailsToServer:_userDetailsDictionary];



}
```

Comment: Please post a code so that we can help . Set it as params and try placing the request in POST format

Comment: check my ans below if suits your scenario.

Comment: I have posted the code.Please check now.

Comment: @vaibav, He is using NSURLSessionDataTask. How it is same with NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if want to know whether the data is successfully submitted to server or not. Just use,

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *serverResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    if (serverResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        NSLog(@"Data successfully submitted in server");
        NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

}];
```